# How to pass a third-party column after a GroupBy and aggregation in PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame, say `df`, to which I need to apply a GroupBy `col1`, aggregate by maximum value of `col2` and pass the corresponding value of `col3` (which has nothing to do with the groupBy or the aggregation). It is best to illustrate it with an example.

```py
df.show()

+-----+-----+-----+
| col1| col2| col3|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    1|  500|  10 |
|    1|  600|  11 |
|    1|  700|  12 |
|    2|  600|  14 |
|    2|  800|  15 |
|    2|  650|  17 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I can easily perform the `groupBy` and the aggregation to obtain the maximum value of each group in `col2`, using

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.groupBy("col1").agg(
    F.max("col2").alias('Max_col2')).show()

+-----+---------+
| col1| Max_col2|
+-----+---------+
|    1|      700|
|    2|      800|
+-----+---------+
```

However, what I am struggling with and what I would like to do is to, additionally, pass the corresponding value of `col3`, thus obtaining the following table:

```py
+-----+---------+-----+
| col1| Max_col2| col3|
+-----+---------+-----+
|    1|      700|  12 |
|    2|      800|  15 |
+-----+---------+-----+
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Many thanks in advance,

Marioanzas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate the maximum of a struct, and then expand the struct:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('col1').agg(
    F.max(F.struct('col2', 'col3')).alias('col')
).select('col1', 'col.*')

df2.show()
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1| 700|  12|
|   2| 800|  15|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Hi @mck , many thanks (once again) for your answer. 
Please correct me if I am wrong: does your code initially compare and find the max of the first elements of the struct? If the elements are not equal it will return the struct with higher value, otherwise it will proceed with comparing the second element of the struct?

Comment: Ok I see, thank you so much. I will try it out and validate your answer shortly. Thanks:)